# Command to browse through the directory to load a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I want to load a csv file that is in my directory. I want to know any command in `r` that will allow me to browse and load my file. I use `read.csv("file.name")` to load a file. Thanks

Comment: There is `list.dirs`, `list.files` that are the most basic ways to interrogate the file system if that's what you're after...? To filter according to extension, use regex: `list.files(path = "some_directory", pattern = ".*\\.csv")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `file.choose()` option :

`read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)` to walk through your directory to select a file and load. In case you don't want `header` then set `header=FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its cool, helps me to go through to choose file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pre-select only the csv files available in the working directory (that could be very useful in some cases), i suggest this command: (and i admit it's not from me, i adapted it from an R forum)

```
read.csv(choose.files(multi = FALSE, filters = cbind("Fichier csv (*.csv)", "*.csv")), sep=";",header=TRUE)
```

I guess you'll have to translate the "Fichier csv" regex (from my French OP) according to what appears on your own language menu.